# How can the analytical solution of the diffusion equation be used for a series of $N$ positions?

Tags: computational-physics, differential-equations, diffusion

Given the exact solution to the diffusion equation:

$$C(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi D t}} \exp\left[-\frac{x^2}{4 D t}\right]$$

I am unsure as how it can be applied to a 1D series, as this equation does not take into account $x_{i-1}$ or $x_{i+1}$.

Whereas a discrete solution does this for both time $t$ and $i\in[1,N]$ positions:

$$C_{i}^{t+1}=C_{i}^{t}+ D \frac{(C_{i+1}^{t}-2C_{i}^{t}+C_{i-1}^{t})}{\Delta x^2}$$

Is there a way of connecting these two methods?

Comment: Do you realize that $x$ in the diffusion equation and $x_i$ in your discrete solution do not represent the same thing, i.e. in the diffusion equation it is the spatial coordinate while in the discrete solution it is the concentration? To avoid confusion, I would write the discrete solution using consistent variables as: $$C_{i}^{t+1}=C_{i}^{t}+ D \frac{(C_{i+1}^{t}-2C_{i}^{t}+C_{i-1}^{t})}{\Delta x^2}$$ where $C_{i}^t=C(x_i, t)$.

Comment: @nluigi No, I hadn't realised, sorry. Thank you for highlighting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second is equation is nearly the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) in discrete form. This is done using the approximation,
$$
u'(x)\simeq\frac{1}{\Delta x}\left(u(x+\Delta x)-u(x)\right)
$$
which should [look reasonably familiar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Geometric_meaning).

If you [make $x$ discrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization), rather than continuous, you have:
$$
u'(x_i)=\frac{1}{\Delta x}\left(u(x_{i+1})-u(x_i)\right)
$$
or, more commonly,
$$
u'_i=\frac{1}{\Delta x}\left(u_{i+1}-u_i\right).
$$
Second derivatives follow naturally from this.

So your second equation is a $\Delta t$ from completing the heat equation:<sup>1</sup>
$$
C_i^{n+1}=C_i^n+D\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2}\left(C_{i+1}^n+C_{i-1}^n-2C_i^n\right)\tag{1}
$$
where $n$ indicates the discrete time coordinate. Contrast this approximation of the heat equation with your first equation,
$$
C(x,\,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}\exp\left[-\frac{x^2}{4Dt}\right]\tag{2}
$$
which is a [specific solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Fundamental_solutions) to the heat equation. If you've implemented the algorithm for Eq. (1) correctly, then the solution of Eq. (2) should match the resulting $C^n$ (at least to truncation error) for the delta-function initial condition.

<sup>1. It might also be the case that they're using $\Delta t\equiv1$, in which case it *is* the discrete form of the heat equation.</sup>

Comment: I don't understand how the initial condition for Eq. (2) is set though?

If $X = [0,0,1,0,0]$ then applying Eq. (1) to each element will create a series of $C$ for each point in $X$ right? Eq. (2) doesn't consider the surrounding values in the series?

Comment: Eq. 2 is the *solution* for $t>0$. For $t=0$, you set $C_{N/2}=1$ and all other $C_i=0$, then evolve it using Eq. 1. At time $t=n\Delta t$, the numerical solution should approximate the analytic one.

Comment: Yes, $C_i^n=C(x_i,\,t_n)$. So using the discrete space of $x_i$, you get a set of $C_i$ values. You then will *update* $C_i$ in each time step. With Eq. 2, it is a continuous function, but you can value it at the $x_i$ points and compare it to the solutions $C_i$.

Comment: To make this more clear: Eq. 1 is how you *approximate* the analytic solution of Eq. 2 using numerical methods (this may be the equivocation you are looking for).